# Set static property and call non-static method

Tags: php, reflection, properties

I have class `Filter`:

```
class Filter
{
   private static $filters = array('foo', 'bar');

   public function getFilters()
   {
      return self::$filters;
   }
}
```

This class has no setter for `$filters`, but I need to change its value. In my opinion, reflection is good way to achieve this, so I tried:

```
$filter = new Filter(); // Create instance of my object

$reflection = new ReflectionObject($filter); // Create its reflection

$filters = $reflection->getProperty('filters'); // Get property reflection ...
$filters->setAccessible(true); // ... and set it to public

$filters->setValue(null, array()); // Set new value
```

Now, `$filters` should be empty, but when I call `$filter->getFilters()`, there are still old values. How to tell class to "use" values which I set in reflection? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `setAccessible` and `setValue` are not methods from reflectionobject

Comment: I know, I am calling them on ReflectionProperty. `$filters = $reflection->getProperty('filters');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solve it myself. All what i have to do is create new instance from reflection:

```
$filter = new Filter();

$reflection = new ReflectionObject($filter);

$filters = $reflection->getProperty('filters');
$filters->setAccessible(true);

$filters->setValue(null, array());

$filter = $reflection->newInstance();

$filter->getFilters(); // It's correct now
```